# Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime cannot be cast to java.base/java.lang.String

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-jpa, liquibase

После первого запуска работает норм, потом падает (после первого всмысле удалть все таблицы из бд и создать их заново)

Использую spring jpa 2.4.5 + liquibase 3.4.1

Полный стек трейс:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [com/coherentsolutions/nastyabakhshieva/config/jpa/DataJpaConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime cannot be cast to java.base/java.lang.String
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:917)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:582)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4714)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5177)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:706)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1727)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:288)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:459)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:408)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:288)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:75)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1406)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:827)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:567)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:800)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:682)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime cannot be cast to java.base/java.lang.String
        at liquibase.changelog.StandardChangeLogHistoryService.getRanChangeSets(StandardChangeLogHistoryService.java:253)
        at liquibase.changelog.AbstractChangeLogHistoryService.upgradeChecksums(AbstractChangeLogHistoryService.java:63)
        at liquibase.changelog.StandardChangeLogHistoryService.upgradeChecksums(StandardChangeLogHistoryService.java:224)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.checkLiquibaseTables(Liquibase.java:1076)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:203)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:190)
        at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:434)
        at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:391)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)
        ... 59 more
=====================================================
17-Mar-2021 16:13:29.858 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.41
17-Mar-2021 16:13:29.859 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Dec 3 2020 11:43:00 UTC
17-Mar-2021 16:13:29.860 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.41.0
17-Mar-2021 16:13:29.860 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
17-Mar-2021 16:13:29.860 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
17-Mar-2021 16:13:29.860 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
17-Mar-2021 16:13:29.860 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4
17-Mar-2021 16:13:29.860 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           9.0.4+11
17-Mar-2021 16:13:29.860 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
17-Mar-2021 16:13:29.860 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\nastyabakhshieva\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.3\tomcat\19574d3a-3da5-4a96-b76d-2045b5ab354e
17-Mar-2021 16:13:29.860 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
17-Mar-2021 16:13:29.861 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
17-Mar-2021 16:13:29.861 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
17-Mar-2021 16:13:29.861 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
17-Mar-2021 16:13:29.861 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\nastyabakhshieva\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.3\tomcat\19574d3a-3da5-4a96-b76d-2045b5ab354e\conf\logging.properties
17-Mar-2021 16:13:29.861 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
17-Mar-2021 16:13:29.861 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
17-Mar-2021 16:13:29.861 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
17-Mar-2021 16:13:29.861 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
17-Mar-2021 16:13:29.861 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=C:\Users\nastyabakhshieva\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.3\tomcat\19574d3a-3da5-4a96-b76d-2045b5ab354e\jmxremote.password
17-Mar-2021 16:13:29.861 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=C:\Users\nastyabakhshieva\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.3\tomcat\19574d3a-3da5-4a96-b76d-2045b5ab354e\jmxremote.access
17-Mar-2021 16:13:29.862 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
17-Mar-2021 16:13:29.862 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
17-Mar-2021 16:13:29.862 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
17-Mar-2021 16:13:29.862 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
17-Mar-2021 16:13:29.862 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\nastyabakhshieva\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.3\tomcat\19574d3a-3da5-4a96-b76d-2045b5ab354e
17-Mar-2021 16:13:29.862 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
17-Mar-2021 16:13:29.862 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\temp
17-Mar-2021 16:13:29.867 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\;C:\Users\nastyabakhshieva\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.1\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_281\bin;C:\Program Files\Maven\bin;C:\Users\nastyabakhshieva\AppData\Local\atom\bin;.]
17-Mar-2021 16:13:29.988 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
17-Mar-2021 16:13:30.012 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [260] milliseconds
17-Mar-2021 16:13:30.040 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
17-Mar-2021 16:13:30.040 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.41]
17-Mar-2021 16:13:30.046 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
17-Mar-2021 16:13:30.051 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [38] milliseconds
Connected to server
[2021-03-17 04:13:30,410] Artifact web-application:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
17-Mar-2021 16:13:32.397 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
17-Mar-2021 16:13:33.454 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper.logPersistenceUnitInformation HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
17-Mar-2021 16:13:33.544 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.Version.logVersion HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.28.Final
17-Mar-2021 16:13:33.777 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.<clinit> HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
17-Mar-2021 16:13:34.255 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.<init> HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
17-Mar-2021 16:13:34.659 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version.<clinit> HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.0.16.Final
17-Mar-2021 16:13:35.368 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator.initiateService HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
INFO 3/17/21, 4:13 PM: liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
INFO 3/17/21, 4:13 PM: liquibase: Reading from java_spring.DATABASECHANGELOG
INFO 3/17/21, 4:13 PM: liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
17-Mar-2021 16:13:37.256 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
17-Mar-2021 16:13:37.290 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
17-Mar-2021 16:13:37.301 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [ROOT] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
[2021-03-17 04:13:37,308] Artifact web-application:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
17-Mar-2021 16:13:40.053 INFO [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\manager]
17-Mar-2021 16:13:40.091 INFO [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\manager] has finished in [38] ms
17-Mar-2021 16:13:40.497 INFO [mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1385)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1038)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.checkThreadContextClassLoader(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:123)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:90)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin\catalina.bat" stop
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\nastyabakhshieva\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.3\tomcat\19574d3a-3da5-4a96-b76d-2045b5ab354e"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Using CATALINA_OPTS:   ""
17-Mar-2021 16:15:17.436 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer No shutdown port configured. Shut down server through OS signal. Server not shut down.
Disconnected from server
```

changelog:

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext
   http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd
   http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
   http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">

    <changeSet id="1.0.0" author="nastya.bakhshieva">
        <sql>
            create table users(
                user_id    bigint          not null  auto_increment,
                first_name varchar(100)    not null,
                last_name  varchar(100)    not null,
                status     varchar(30)     not null  default 'ACTIVE',
                role       varchar(30)     not null  default 'ROLE_USER',
                username   varchar(200)    not null  unique,
                password   varchar(200)    not null,
                constraint pk_user_user_id primary   key(user_id)
            );
        </sql>
        <rollback>
            drop table if exists users;
        </rollback>
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

Entity:

```
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "status")
    private Status status;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "role")
    private Role role;
}
```

db.properties:

```
spring.data.driver-classname=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.data.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java_spring?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.data.username=root
spring.data.password=root
```

config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.repositories")
@PropertySource("classpath:database.properties")
public class DataJpaConfig {

    @Value("${spring.data.driver-classname}")
    private String driver;

    @Value("${spring.data.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${spring.data.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${spring.data.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driver);
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringLiquibase liquibase() {
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:liquibase/db.changelog-master.xml");
        liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return liquibase;
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(false);
        vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect");
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com.coherentsolutions.nastyabakhshieva");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }


    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return txManager;
    }
}
```

liquibase:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не могу представить, судя по ошибке, какую дату он пытается сконвертить в строку - ведь никаких дат в моих энтити нету. В чем может быть проблема?

Еще что примечательно, так это то, что когда я создавала юзеров с ролями связью многие-ко-многим(тоесть требовалось три таблицы вместо одной: юзеры, роли, и связующая) - все работало корректно, и после первого запуска, и последующие, все что изменилось у юзера - появилось поле `role`, а остальные таблицы удалены

Скажите если кто знает, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В какой-то версии mysql коннектора (вроде 8.0.23) что-то поменялось и теперь поле `DATETIME` возвращается как `LocalTime`, а не как наследник `Date`, т.е. `Timestamp`.

Решение 1: поменять коннектор на 22 или ниже:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.22</version>
</dependency>
```

Второе решение находится в `liquibase` в версии `3.4.1`, а конкретно там добавили чек `LocalDateTime`:

```
if (tmpDateExecuted instanceof Date) {
    dateExecuted = (Date)tmpDateExecuted;
} else if (tmpDateExecuted instanceof LocalDateTime) {
    dateExecuted = Date.from(((LocalDateTime)tmpDateExecuted).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
} else {
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    try {
        dateExecuted = df.parse((String)tmpDateExecuted);
    } catch (ParseException var26) {}
}
```

Так что проверяйте, точно ли у вас 3.4.1.

В итоге зависимости выглядят примерно так:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.23</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Вы правы! спустила версию коннектора на пару минорных версий и все заработало!